# WPF Binding Returns the wrong Object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, datatemplate

I have a ListBox in WPF where I set ItemsSource Property in Code to a List of "List"

When i now run the Program, i get a List with my classname with as much entrys as the List contains. Thats correct.

Now i secify the following Datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor DisplayNetwork="{Binding}"></NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor>
</DataTemplate>
```

But to the DependencyPropery "DisplayNetwork" is always passed "null" (I tested this with a DebugValueConverter).

Any Ideas?

Xaml of the List Box:

```
<ListBox Name="myLst" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>               
            <DataTemplate>
                <NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor DisplayNetwork="{Binding}"></NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor>
            </DataTemplate>          
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListBox>
```

Implementaion of the Property in my UserControl:

```
public Network DisplayNetwork
    {
        get { return (Network)GetValue(DisplayNetworkProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayNetworkProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayNetwork.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayNetworkProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayNetwork", typeof(Network), typeof(NetworkEditor), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnDisplayNetworkChanged, CoerceValueCallback));

    private static Object CoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d,Object baseValue)
    {
        return baseValue;
    }
```

OnDisplayNetworkChanged is never called, because null is always set as Value!

Data Source of my ListBox:

```
myLst.ItemsSource = ((S7FunctionBlock) myBlock).Networks;
```

where Networks is a List, and when I debug this Line, it contains data!

Comment: Could you show the Xaml of the ListBox?

Comment: Is the myBlock.Networks filled when assigning it to the ItemsSource property? and does it contain items (Network instances?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your `NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor` class, if you set the DataContext there in. It is an often made mistake to set the DataContext from within a class and then to try accessing the DataContext from Xaml on this tag, thinking that the parents DataContext will be returned.

For checking this, try to change your XAML to the following.

```
<DataTemplate>      
    <Grid>
        <NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor DisplayNetwork="{Path=DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource,Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}}">
        </NetworkEditor:NetworkEditor> 
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Make a comment if there is an error in, I have not tested it. However, as also Will Dean says, in this case changing the NetworkEditor would be a good idea, if it is under your control.

Answer (score 1):

As HCL says, the DataContext of that control is probably not what you think it is.

To diagnose this, you could change {Binding} to {Binding SomethingThatDoesntExist}, then turn on binding warnings in VS.   The binding warning message will tell you which type of object was checked for 'SomethingThatDoesntExist' - you'll probably find it's not what you expected.

If it does turn out to be that NetworkEditor is setting its DataContext to something different to what you think, then a good solution to this problem (provided NetworkEditor is under your control), is to change to setting DataContext on the first object within NetworkEditor (often a Grid in a typical UserControl), rather than on the NetworkEditor object itself.

Comment: +1, Setting the DataContext to a child-control of NetworkEditor seems to me a good advice.